# How to remove "unknown member VERSION_CODE of com.architjn.materialicons.Build.Config " error in AIDE

Tags: aide-ide

I was building an android icon pack from this Material icon pack template library https://github.com/architjn/MaterialIconPackTemplate in AIDE . The IDE (AIDE) is showing this error "unknown member VERSION_CODE of com.architjn.materialicons.Build.Config " in home fragment .java file located in https://github.com/architjn/MaterialIconPackTemplate/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/architjn/materialicons/ui/fragments/HomeFragment.java and i am unable to solve this problem. I had tried to fix it by IDE's option create public static final int VERSION CODE and the second option and then saved the file ,it even stopped showing the error before building the app but when i press the run button , while compiling it shows the error again. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file named as ***BuildConfig.java*** and add the following code in it -

```
package your.package.name;

public final class BuildConfig {

    public static int VERSION_CODE = 1;
}
```

Here the value of int should be the value of the Versuon Code of the App...